# how to implement docker command "docker logs -f ......" display color

Tags: docker

i run docker command "`docker run -t XXXXXX`" can display log color, but "`docker logs -f XXXXXX`" don't display log color, how can i implement it by "`docker logs -f`"

Answer (score 1):

you can use [GRC](https://github.com/garabik/grc) and add it with command as pipeline

```
docker logs test-demo | grc
```